# I get an error when installing django with pipenv

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install django=4.0.1 on my mac with pipenv.
(1) my python: /usr/bin/python3 (3.7.3)
(2) my pipenv version: version 2022.1.8
(3) I just updated 'pip'

But I get a message below

[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==4.0.1 (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10, 1.11.11, 1.11.12, 1.11.13, 1.11.14, 1.11.15, 1.11.16, 1.11.17, 1.11.18, 1.11.20, 1.11.21, 1.11.22, 1.11.23, 1.11.24, 1.11.25, 1.11.26, 1.11.27, 1.11.28, 1.11.29, 2.0a1, 2.0b1, 2.0rc1, 2.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.0.10, 2.0.12, 2.0.13, 2.1a1, 2.1b1, 2.1rc1, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.7, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.1.10, 2.1.11, 2.1.12, 2.1.13, 2.1.14, 2.1.15, 2.2a1, 2.2b1, 2.2rc1, 2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.2.6, 2.2.7, 2.2.8, 2.2.9, 2.2.10, 2.2.11, 2.2.12, 2.2.13, 2.2.14, 2.2.15, 2.2.16, 2.2.17, 2.2.18, 2.2.19, 2.2.20, 2.2.21, 2.2.22, 2.2.23, 2.2.24, 2.2.25, 2.2.26, 3.0a1, 3.0b1, 3.0rc1, 3.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.6, 3.0.7, 3.0.8, 3.0.9, 3.0.10, 3.0.11, 3.0.12, 3.0.13, 3.0.14, 3.1a1, 3.1b1, 3.1rc1, 3.1, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.4, 3.1.5, 3.1.6, 3.1.7, 3.1.8, 3.1.9, 3.1.10, 3.1.11, 3.1.12, 3.1.13, 3.1.14, 3.2a1, 3.2b1, 3.2rc1, 3.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 3.2.4, 3.2.5, 3.2.6, 3.2.7, 3.2.8, 3.2.9, 3.2.10, 3.2.11)

[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: No matching distribution found for django==4.0.1

Is there a way I can install django 4.0.1?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because django 4.0.1 isn't avalible for python 3.7.3. It's only available for python 3.8+, try to change your python version

Answer (score 2):

You got this error because you use python 3,7. Django 4.x support only python 3.8+